# Need to get in DATE Format (YYYY-MM-DD) from a NUMBER Data type column (123456789)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with datatype `NUMBER(32,0)`. This column actually stores the date and time stamp from the application.

I need to export this `number` data type column as `date`.

i.e.,

```
select column_name from table_name;

 o/p:
1368046452000
```

I tried this option to export as Date,

```
SELECT TO_DATE( 
         TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01'
                     ,'YYYY-MM-DD'
         ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(column_name/1000, 'SECOND')
        ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM  table_name;
```

It gives me the output `"15-JUL-23"` as expected.

Question:

This table has around 900+ columns and in which 50+ columns are like this number data_type which stored the date and time in it. I need to convert/format these 50+ columns into `YYYY-MM-DD`.

How can I get/export/select all the column values from the table in which the above number data_type columns should return with `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Please help!!

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: 900+ columns. Are you serious? dates stored as number, Are you serious?

Comment: If you are looking to create a new table, you could create the table from a select of the current table with the proper types. Or you could create a view/materialized view with the proper types. Are you changing the application to insert the correct date types in the future?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, yes. The table is having 900+ columns and the 50+ columns are number datatype which is storing the date and time in numbers.. Need to just export these number data type values into as date format. Can you please help?

Comment: @ZynonPutneyII. We are not touching the current table because these tables are directly used by the application front end and we are not going to alter the current table now and in future. I just need to export in excel sheet using sql deveoper, the date and time values which is stored in number data type into a DATE format. Please suggest!

Comment: Do not use `TO_DATE` on something that is already a `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) data type as `TO_DATE` expects a string as its first argument and then you get into issues when the default date-to-string format does not match your explicit `YYYY-MM-DD` format ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dd3c88d900aa2c034af552eba3b90e6e) with its defaults gives an `ORA-01858` exception for your query). If you want to convert a `TIMESTAMP` to a `DATE` then use `CAST( value AS DATE )`.

Comment: @KarthikPon the issue will be the same regardless of what dev tool you use, so I'm not sure SQL Developer is really relevant here.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes. I know it's not related to SQL developer. I am looking for the solution to export all the 900+ columns in this table (eg., select * from table_name) with the date format (CAST) applied to the 50+ number data type columns. Could you please help? Any suggestions plz?

Answer (score 3):

Your time appears to the a Unix timestamp which will measure milliseconds since 1970-01-01 in the **UTC** time zone.

You can use:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND
FROM   table_name;
```

Which will get the value as a `TIMESTAMP` data type (since it can have fractional seconds).

If you want it as a `DATE` then use `CAST` to convert it:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   table_name;
```

If you want it in a specific time zone (and not UTC) then use `AT TIME ZONE 'your_tz'`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND )
           AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
           AS DATE
       )
FROM   table_name;
```

So for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_name ) AS
SELECT 1368046452000 FROM DUAL;
```

the query:

```sql
SELECT ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND )
         AS UTC_TIMESTAMP,
       CAST(
         ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND )
           AS DATE
       ) AS UTC_DATE,
       CAST(
         ( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + column_name * INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND )
           AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
           AS DATE
       ) AS PST_DATE
FROM   table_name;
```

would output:

> ```
> UTC_TIMESTAMP                     | UTC_DATE            | PST_DATE           
> :-------------------------------- | :------------------ | :------------------
> 2013-05-08 20:54:12.000000000 UTC | 2013-05-08 20:54:12 | 2013-05-08 13:54:12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4028b9df7c56322f979968bda3709d7)*

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i get the list of all the 900+ columns in this table including the date format (as you suggested above) applied to all the number data type columns in it?

Answer (score 0):

Just for heck of less coding, create a function

```
Create or replace function MyConvert(p_val in number ) return varchar2
as
begin
    return TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970/01/01 00:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') + 
                NUMTODSINTERVAL(p_val / 1000,'SECOND'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
end;
```

And then in your code just do

```
SELECT MyConvert(col1) col1, ..... MyConvert(col50) col50 FROM table
```

The "date format" you are getting is not actually a date - this is a string representation of the date

Comment: Unix timestamp are based on UTC time, so result is also UTC time. This might be OK or not - it depends on application requirements (esp. when values are closed to midnight).